# Ceiling fans tripping arc fault breakers

Tags: electric-motor

I an apartment complex I have a lighting circuit that is not on an arc fault breaker. There are 2 ceiling fans on that circuit, each having its own fan speed control.

Intermittently when fans are turned on it trips the other arc fault circuit breakers. I have been in 2 of apartments and have had in both apartments 3 out of 4 arc fault breakers trip at one time. They all have a full range fan control Lutron and I tried a 3 speed control and it made it worse. Does anyone have any ideas of how to fix? I am wondering if it is a surge or harmonic distortion.

Comment: What make and model are these fans, and do you know how old they are for that matter?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

The harmonics generated by variable speed motor controllers confuse AFCI’s and cause them to trip. This is a known defect also heavily loaded lighting circuits with modern ballast and light dimmers are known to cause tripping. They have become slightly better but still have this issue. My state allows the AFCI to be omitted for circuits with known issues. Check with your AHJ. (Authority having jurisdiction), a call to the local inspectors office will usually get a reply within a day sometimes 2 during the week.

Answer (score 0):

That's not unusual.  AFCIs function by *listening* to the power line.  If arcing sounds are loud and close, it's common for AFCIs to hear them, even though they are on a different circuit.  AFCIs don't have a big noise damper inside them, so even though they are monitoring the LOAD side, noise will penetrate through from the LINE side.

I use an acoustic metaphor, for reasons which will be obvious if you've ever hooked up a stereo with external speakers.  There is a very tight metaphor between acoustic noise and electrical line noise, which you are familiar with if you have ever hooked up speakers with the power *on*.

I find it interesting that with *That much* line noise running around your electrical system, your first thought is "AFCIs should be more noise tolerant" and not "Oh no, that line noise must be stopped before it destroys my valuable electronics!"

That is a common misbelief about line noise and surges.  People assume that damaging surges and noise invade your home due to something-something out on the power grid.  "Surely that doesn't apply to *my own* loads!" Oh, yeah.

So your best play might actually be to fit surge suppression on the fan circuit, as close to the speed controllers as possible.  The smaller Eaton or Siemens whole-house units come to mind.